# Limiting property of a sequence of stochastic processes - How to interpret it?

Tags: stochastic-processes

What is the interpretation of

$$ \lim_{a \to \infty} \sup_n P \Big( \sup_t |X_t^n| \geq a \Big) = 0$$

where $\{X^n_t\}_n$ is a sequence of stochastic processes?

Could we say that the paths $X^n$ almost never "explode"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y_n:=\sup_t|X_t^n|$. Then $\{Y_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is a sequence of random elements. The condition can be written as
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty}\sup_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(Y_n\ge a)=0.
$$
This is the definition of the (uniform) tightness of a stochastic process. It is equivalent to saying that for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $K_{\epsilon}<\infty$ (if each $X_t^n$ is real valued) s.t. $\mathsf{P}(Y_n> K_{\epsilon})<\epsilon$ for each $n\ge 1$, i.e.,
$$
Y_n=O_p(1).
$$

Comment: When you write "...this is the definition of tightness of a stochastic process" are you referring to the (discrete-time) process $Y_n$ (indexed by $n$)? Or is tightness referring to the each of the processes $X_t^n$ in the sequence indexed by $n$? Do you have a reference for tightness of stochastic processes; I only managed to find definitions for measures.

Comment: @harisf (1) I'm referring to $\{Y_n\}$. (2) $\{Y_n\}$ is tight if the corresponding distributions form a tight family of measures.

Answer (score 1):

This condition certainly implies that the paths almost never explode, but is stronger than that.  I would interpret this condition as "uniform boundedness in probability": There exists $K \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|X_t^n| \le K$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, t \ge 0$ with high probability.